# How to stop Custom OnSaving event after first saving in SItecore?

Tags: c#, sitecore

I am trying to stop my custom OnSaving event after it has been applied to the first item in the save chain.

but so far I have not been able to, and I end up with a stackoverflow exception.

Is there a simple way of doing this ?

Best regards,

Robin

```
private void AddOrRemoveRedirectingItemIdFromSavingItemIdList(Item savingItem, SitecoreEventArgs sitecoreEventArgs)
{
    ItemLink[] referers = Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferrers(savingItem);

    var guidList = new List<ID>();

    foreach (ItemLink link in referers)
    {
        // checking the database name of the linked Item
        if (!link.SourceDatabaseName.Equals(Context.ContentDatabase.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            continue;
        }

        Item item = Context.ContentDatabase.Items[link.SourceItemID, savingItem.Language];

        // adding the Item to an array if the Item is not null
        if (item == null || item.Fields["301Redirect"] == null || item.Fields["301RedirectedTo"] == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Update the saving item ids
        CheckboxField redirectField = item.Fields["301Redirect"];

        if (redirectField.Checked)
        {
            guidList.Add(item.ID);
        }
    }

    if (guidList.Any())
    {
        this.SaveIDsToEditingItem(savingItem, guidList, false);
    }
}

private void SaveIDsToEditingItem(Item editingItem, IEnumerable<ID> guidList, bool forceModified)
{
    Field redirectedToFromItemId = editingItem.Fields["301RedirectedToFromItemId"];

    using (new EditContext(editingItem))
    {
        // Saving the redirected items ids
        string redirectedToFromItemIdOld = redirectedToFromItemId.Value;
        string redirectedToFromItemIdNew = string.Join("\n", guidList.Select(guid => guid.ToString()));

        // if the values are not changed
        if (redirectedToFromItemIdNew.Equals(redirectedToFromItemIdOld))
        {
            return;
        }

        redirectedToFromItemId.Value = redirectedToFromItemIdNew;
        if (forceModified)
        {
            editingItem.RuntimeSettings.ForceModified = true;
        }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code? What is your custom event doing?

Comment: Yes, code please. It sounds like you are updating and saving the item in the event. You should just edit the item in the args and let it process continue on.

Comment: Its a rather big chunk of code, the essential stuff going on is that I am adding and removing id's from referenced items.

Comment: Like an item is set to redirect to another item (target item), and I want to update the target item with a list of id's that is redirecting to this target item, and I also try to run through the links database to ensure that this list is updated when I save the target item

Comment: From what it sounds, it would be enough to check if the new list of redirecting items is different from the current one. And if it is the same, just not save the item again. Or do I miss something?

Comment: You mean that when the chain encounters the same item as the one I am updating I should just ignore it ?

Comment: I realized that because I update other items, it fires a new OnSaving event for that item, so I don't know how to reference the first item in the chain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this 2 ways. The better way would be to remove the `using (new EditingContext(editingItem)` section from the `SaveIDsToEditingItem`. In the `OnItemSaving` event, any changes made to the `savingItem` would be kept.

Alternatively, if you *need* to use the editing context for some reason you need to use an EventDisabler in your `SaveIDsToEditingItem` method:

```
private void SaveIDsToEditingItem(Item editingItem, IEnumerable<ID> guidList, bool forceModified)
{
    Field redirectedToFromItemId = editingItem.Fields["301RedirectedToFromItemId"];

    using (new EventDisabler())
    {
        using (new EditContext(editingItem))
        {
            // Saving the redirected items ids
            string redirectedToFromItemIdOld = redirectedToFromItemId.Value;
            string redirectedToFromItemIdNew = string.Join("\n", guidList.Select(guid => guid.ToString()));

            // if the values are not changed
            if (redirectedToFromItemIdNew.Equals(redirectedToFromItemIdOld))
            {
                return;
            }

            redirectedToFromItemId.Value = redirectedToFromItemIdNew;
            if (forceModified)
            {
                editingItem.RuntimeSettings.ForceModified = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will prevent the `OnSaving` event from being fired again.

Comment: Thank you, I had completely forgotten that there was an EventDisabler, I rarely need to use this, but in this case it is necessary.